# array in R error in next variable

Tags: arrays, r

So i try to assign value in array. I write the code in R studio

[image]

And it works. The results are correct.
But when I insert the third variable, it comes with error. so does the fourth variable and so on

[image]

I've tried other names for the third variable but the error is still there. Whats the problem ? Thank in advance

Comment: You don't do this way in R. Things are vectorized. `a<-3*(1:10)`  (and similar for the others) is the way, without any loop. The error you received couldn't be clearer: the `bb` object doesn't exist and so R can't assign to the i-th element of it the value `5*i`. Apparently, you defined `a` and `b` somewhere before the loop, but not `bb`. But that's not important: define `bb<-5*(1:10)` as I said before without loops and everything will be ok.

Comment: @Nicola : I need to do the looping. Currently Im using shiny and need those kind of logic for array. Anyway you solved it. Defining the variable first make it works. Thanks!

Comment: I bet you don't need to loop, if the real problem just vaguely resembles the one you are presenting. Anyway, I suggest you to better understand vectorization. The accepted solution is *very* inefficient in R, compared to the vectorization I proposed.

Comment: @Nicola. if it's about efficiency, then I ll search more about that vectorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you facing is:

you are not declaring `'bb'`, so try to declare `'bb'` before use it.

```
> bb<-0
> for(i in 1:10){
+   a[i]=3*i
+   b[i]=4*i
+   bb[i]=5*i
+ }
> bb[3]
[1] 15
```